# Is there any Java x509certificate ClientHello parser in Java?

Tags: java, networking, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I got a packet of bytes which are the `ClientHello` of SSL protocol packet.

Before I'm starting to code by myself, a code which is going through all over the bytes to get each field value, I wonder if there is any Java Object (from java.security) which is used to get these bytes and parse the data so I would be able to take the SSL protocol fields and use them?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the real problem you are trying to solve by looking at the protocol fields?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes, just to get all the fields using any exist `Java` code which already done this job before instead of coding it all over by myself

Comment: So you don't want to do a SSL connection and get information about the peer but instead want to parse a ClientHello you got from somewhere (packet capture...), is this correct?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, yes my friend

Comment: I'm not aware of any library which encapsulates all this but there is sample code at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/samples/sni/SSLExplorer.java.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich is there any `Java` built-in classes which makes the same?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich any idea which class can make me this parsing ?

Comment: Again: I'm not aware of any library .....

Comment: `ClientHello` doesn't have anything whatsoever to do with X.509 certificates. *Of course* there are Java classes that can parse SSL messages, as Java already supports SSL in its entirety. Question and purpose remain unclear

Comment: great question.  we have the same problem, we need to read the SNI fields before letting handshake process proceed.  I assume at least you also need it pre-handshake and if not, then just use SSLEngine.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, the `java.security` package in Java does not provide any functionality along the lines of what you're looking for.  There may be other examples/libraries on GitHub.

If you end up doing this yourself, key things to be aware of are:

- [SSLv2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hickman-netscape-ssl-00) *vs* SSLv3 *vs* TLSv1 [`ClientHello`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2) formats
- Your question title mentions certificates; client certificates are *not* present `ClientHello` messages; they are only sent later in the handshake process, in response to a [`CertificateRequest`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.4) message from the server.

Decoding SSL/TLS messages usually involves reading (and re-reading) the relevant RFCs, and figuring out what each byte value signifies, by its position within the packet.  Being designed as a binary protocol, for efficiency, it can be more complicated to tease out the fields you want than you might think necessary.  But it's well-worth gaining an understanding of these fields.

Here's some Java code which might help to get you started.  **Note** that it uses byte buffers in Java, as it is necessary to deal with *unsigned* data types when decoding binary protocols like this.

```
// These values are defined in the IETF TLS cipher suite registry; see:
//
//   http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xml#tls-parameters-3
private static final int RC4_MD5_HEX = 0x0004;
private static final int RC4_SHA_HEX = 0x0005;

private static final short HANDSHAKE_CONTENT_TYPE = 22;
private static final short CLIENTHELLO_MESSAGE_TYPE = 1;

private static final short SSLV2_CLIENTHELLO = 128;
protected boolean doDecode(IoSession session,
                           IoBufferEx original,
                           ProtocolDecoderOutput out)
    throws Exception {

    // Need at least 2 bytes to differentiate between SSLv2 ClientHello
    // messages and SSLv3/TLSv1/+ messages.
    //
    // For SSLv2 ClientHello, we need:
    //
    //  length header (short)
    //  content type (byte)
    //
    // For more details, see:
    //
    //  https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hickman-netscape-ssl-00
    //
    // Otherwise, we need:
    //
    //  content type (byte)
    //  version (short)
    //  length (short)
    //
    // So wait for at least 5 bytes, to cover either case.

    if (original.remaining() < 5) {
        return false;
    }

    // Make a copy, so that we can read things non-destructively
    IoBufferEx dup = original.duplicate();

    // If not a Handshake record, be done.  Note that we have to
    // successfully handle SSLv2 ClientHello formats as well.

    short contentType = dup.getUnsigned();
    if (contentType == HANDSHAKE_CONTENT_TYPE) {
        // Skip the ProtocolVersion here; we will get it later
        dup.skip(2);

        int recordSize = dup.getUnsignedShort();

        // Now wait until we have the entire record
        if (original.remaining() < (5 + recordSize)) {
            // Keep buffering
            return false;
        }

    } else if (contentType == SSLV2_CLIENTHELLO) {
        short len = dup.getUnsigned();

        // Decode the length
        int recordSize = ((contentType & 0x7f) << 8 | len);

        // Now wait until we have the entire record
        if (original.remaining() < (2 + recordSize)) {
            // Keep buffering
            return false;
        }

    } else { 
        // We're only interested in Handshake records
        out.write(original.getSlice(original.remaining()));
        return true;
    }

    // For the format of the ClientHello message, see RFC 5246,
    // Section 7.4.1.2.

    short messageType = dup.getUnsigned();
    if (messageType != CLIENTHELLO_MESSAGE_TYPE) {
        // We're only interested in ClientHello messages
        out.write(original.getSlice(original.remaining()));
        return true;
    }

    if (contentType == HANDSHAKE_CONTENT_TYPE) {
        // If we're not an SSLv2 ClientHello, then skip the ClientHello
        // message size.
        dup.skip(3);

        // Use the ClientHello ProtocolVersion
        SslVersion version = SslVersion.decode(dup.getUnsignedShort());

        // Skip ClientRandom
        dup.skip(32);

        // Skip SessionID
        int sessionIDSize = dup.getUnsigned();
        dup.skip(sessionIDSize);

        // Now we get to what we're really after: the ciphersuites supported
        // by the client.
        int cipherSuiteSize = dup.getUnsignedShort();

        // cipherSuiteSize is the number of bytes; each cipher is specified
        // using a short (2 bytes).  Thus the cipher suite count is the half
        // the cipher suite size.
        int cipherSuiteCount = cipherSuiteSize / 2;

        // Iterate through each of the ciphersuites

        for (int i = 0; i < cipherSuiteCount; i++) {
            int cipher = dup.getUnsignedShort();

            if (cipher == RC4_SHA_HEX) {
                ciphers.add(SslCipherSelectionFilter.RC4_SHA);

            } else if (cipher == RC4_MD5_HEX) {
                ciphers.add(SslCipherSelectionFilter.RC4_MD5);
            }
        }

    } else {
        // SSLv2 ClientHello.
        // Use the ClientHello ProtocolVersion
        SslVersion version = SslVersion.decode(dup.getUnsignedShort());

        // Determine cipher specs size
        short msb = dup.getUnsigned();
        short lsb = dup.getUnsigned();
        int cipherSuiteSize = ((msb << 8) | lsb);

        // Skip the sessionID size
        dup.skip(2);

        // Skip the challenge size
        dup.skip(2);

        // Now we get to what we're really after: the ciphersuites supported
        // by the client.

        // cipherSuiteSize is the number of bytes; each cipher is specified
        // using a medium int (3 bytes).
        int cipherSuiteCount = cipherSuiteSize / 3;

        // Iterate through each of the ciphersuites, looking for 
        // SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5.  (It's the only one supported in
        // SSLv2 ClientHellos).

        for (int i = 0; i < cipherSuiteCount; i++) {
            int cipherKind = dup.getUnsignedMediumInt();

            if (cipherKind == SSLV2_RC4_MD5_HEX) {
                appletCiphers.add(SslCipherSelectionFilter.RC4_MD5);
            }
        }
    }

    out.write(original.getSlice(original.remaining()));
    return true;
}
```

See this [SslClientHelloDecoder.java](https://github.com/kaazing/gateway/blob/5216140c3e02b460dc14886a4f56ad51b1dac9ba/transport/ssl/src/main/java/org/kaazing/gateway/transport/ssl/bridge/filter/SslClientHelloDecoder.java) file for the rest of the code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: not sure who gave you a -1 but this answer rocked (+1 to revert the -1) !!!! thanks!!!  This is great as we need some info before we allow the handshake process to start as well.