# how to convert first hello SSL message into jdk ClientHello.java object?

Tags: java, ssl

before I create the SSLEngine, I need the SNI server name in the extensions of the very first SSL client hello (if it exists of course).  I am looking at the ClientHello class here...(though I am in jdk 8 right now).

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/file/6407a15e2274/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage.java

Does anyone know how I can more easily go from ByteBuffer to data structure to grab the SNI servername?   (the bytebuffer will contain a size equal or greater than that required as I already check the size of the SSL packet and wait until I have the full ssl hello packet).

Also, this post was working quite well for getting the starting pieces in place [Is there any Java x509certificate ClientHello parser in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131970/is-there-any-java-x509certificate-clienthello-parser-in-java#comment56014606_34131970)

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone else to re-use but this is my first go at it and it worked such that I can grab the sniServerName before the handshake even starts...

```
public class ClientHelloParser {
private static final short HANDSHAKE_CONTENT_TYPE = 22;
private static final short CLIENTHELLO_MESSAGE_TYPE = 1;
private static final short SSLV2_CLIENTHELLO = 128;

private static final int SERVER_NAME_EXTENSION_TYPE = 0;
private static final short HOST_NAME_TYPE = 0;

private ByteBuffer cachedBuffer;
private BufferPool pool;

public ClientHelloParser(BufferPool pool) {
    this.pool = pool;
}

/**
 * Returns null if we still need more data
 * 
 * @param b
 * @return
 */
ParseResult fetchServerNamesIfEntirePacketAvailable(ByteBuffer b) {
    if(cachedBuffer != null) {
        //prefix cachedBuffer in front of b and assign to b as the packet that is coming in
        ByteBuffer newBuf = pool.nextBuffer(cachedBuffer.remaining()+b.remaining());
        newBuf.put(cachedBuffer);
        newBuf.put(b);
        newBuf.flip();
        pool.releaseBuffer(b); //release b that is now in the newBuf
        pool.releaseBuffer(cachedBuffer); //release cached buffer that is now in newBuf
        b = newBuf;
    }

    if(b.remaining() < 5) {
        cachedBuffer = b;
        return null; //wait for more data
    }

    int recordSize = 0;
    ByteBuffer duplicate = b.duplicate();
    short contentType = getUnsignedByte(duplicate);
    if(contentType == HANDSHAKE_CONTENT_TYPE) {
        getUnsignedByte(duplicate);
        getUnsignedByte(duplicate);
        recordSize = getUnsignedShort(duplicate);

          // Now wait until we have the entire record
        if (b.remaining() < (5 + recordSize)) {
            // Keep buffering
            return null;
        }                   
    } else if (contentType == SSLV2_CLIENTHELLO) {
        short len = getUnsignedByte(duplicate);

        // Decode the length
        recordSize = ((contentType & 0x7f) << 8 | len);

        // Now wait until we have the entire record
        if (b.remaining() < (2 + recordSize)) {
            // Keep buffering
            return null;
        }

    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("contentType="+contentType+" not supported in ssl hello handshake packet");
    }

    short messageType = getUnsignedByte(duplicate);
    if (messageType != CLIENTHELLO_MESSAGE_TYPE) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("something came before ClientHello :( messageType="+messageType);
    }

    if (contentType == HANDSHAKE_CONTENT_TYPE) {
        // If we're not an SSLv2 ClientHello, then skip the ClientHello
        // message size.
        duplicate.get(new byte[3]);

        // Use the ClientHello ProtocolVersion
        getUnsignedShort(duplicate);

        // Skip ClientRandom
        duplicate.get(new byte[32]);

        // Skip SessionID
        int sessionIDSize = getUnsignedByte(duplicate);
        duplicate.get(new byte[sessionIDSize]);

        //read in and discard cipherSuite...
        int cipherSuiteSize = getUnsignedShort(duplicate);
        duplicate.get(new byte[cipherSuiteSize]);

        //read in compression methods size and discard..
        short compressionMethodsLen = getUnsignedByte(duplicate);
        duplicate.get(new byte[compressionMethodsLen]);

        int extensionLen = getUnsignedShort(duplicate);
        List<String> names = readInExtensionServerNames(duplicate, extensionLen);

        return new ParseResult(b, names);
    } else {
        // SSLv2 ClientHello.
        // Use the ClientHello ProtocolVersion
        //SslVersion version = SslVersion.decode(getUnsignedByte(duplicate));

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not supported yet");
    }
}

private List<String> readInExtensionServerNames(ByteBuffer duplicate, int len) {
    List<String> serverNames = new ArrayList<>();
    int byteCount = 0;
    while(byteCount < len) {
        byteCount += 4;  //reading in 4 bytes so add them in
        if(duplicate.remaining() < 4)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Corrupt packet with incorrect format");
        int type = getUnsignedShort(duplicate);
        int extLen = getUnsignedShort(duplicate);

        if(duplicate.remaining() < extLen)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Corrupt packet with incorrect format as len didn't match");

        if(type == SERVER_NAME_EXTENSION_TYPE) {
            String name = readServerNames(duplicate, extLen);
            serverNames.add(name);
        } else
            duplicate.get(new byte[extLen]);
        byteCount += extLen;
    }

    return serverNames;
}

private String readServerNames(ByteBuffer duplicate, int extLen) {
    int byteCount = 0;

    byteCount += 2; //for listLen 2 bytes
    int listLen = getUnsignedShort(duplicate);
    if(listLen + 2 != extLen)
        throw new RuntimeException("we have something we need to fix here as listLen is only two less bytes then extensionLength");

    byteCount += 1; //for serverNameType
    short serverNameType = getUnsignedByte(duplicate);
    if(serverNameType != HOST_NAME_TYPE)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Server name type="+serverNameType+" not supported yet");

    byteCount += 2; //for serverNameLen
    int serverNameLen = getUnsignedShort(duplicate);

    byteCount += serverNameLen;
    if(byteCount != extLen)
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("bytes read in servernames extension does not match extLen(we need to loop here then)");

    byte[] data = new byte[serverNameLen];
    duplicate.get(data);

    String serverName = new String(data);
    return serverName;
}

public short getUnsignedByte(ByteBuffer bb) {
    return ((short)(bb.get() & 0xff));
}

public int getUnsignedShort (ByteBuffer bb)
{
    return (bb.getShort() & 0xffff);
}
}
```